# How I can display one field as string from serializer?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

I use rest framework, I have field in user emloyee.company which is has field name. I need display only name string, but I have dict.

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name',)


class UserSerializer(MySerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer(source='employee.company')

    class Meta:
        fields = (..., 'company')
```

I've got:

```
{...,"company":{"name":"My company"}}
```

I need:

```
{...,"company":"My company"}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
company = CompanySerializer(source='employee.company')
```

to:

```
company = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='employee.company.name')
```

Comment: Thanks, its work this way: `source='employee.company.name'`

Comment: Whoops, sorry, my typo.